# c# Update label to new property value

Tags: c#, binding, refresh

I have in my form a lblName and a refresh method for the gui refresh. I add a `DataBind`to the label  but if I change the property and call `lblName.Refresh()` or `lblName.Update()` it doesn't change.

```
lblName.DataBindings.Add("Text", testPeople, "Name");
```

I'm working with the Model View Controller pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dataBinding = lblName.DataBindings.Add("Text", testPeople, "Name");
databinding.ReadValue();
```

Comment: its works, but its a bad way or not? because i have more then one label and then i need for every label a binding object.

Comment: No it's not bad, but you can achieve the same without the binding object if you use inotifypropertychanged implemented objects